# Visual Studio 2008 tfs automatically generating .cs file when i directly paste file into solution's folder

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, c#

Visual Studio 2008 tfs automatically generating .cs file when i directly paste file into solution's folder.

every time i paste my .rpt file in VS2008 TFS another 1.cs file generated

Answer (score 0):

Right click on .RPT then properties then paste this to Custom Tool field: CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportCodeGenerator

Comment: dear Captain Yamato 
in all rpt file  custom tool field contains 'CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportCodeGenerator' but same problem.anyway thanks.